# OutOfMemoryException while collecting memory data in PerfView

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, perfview

I'm doing a memory leak investigation using **PerfView** and I'm following [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/Tutorial-10-Investigating-NET-Heap-Memory-Leaks-Part1-Collecting-the-data?ocid=player) and [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/Tutorial-11-Investigating-NET-Heap-Memory-Leaks-Part2-Analyzing-the-data) videos.

However, the server I'm investigating has already taken ~100% of memory, so when I try dump GC heap I get an `OutOfMemoryException` and the dump file isn't created at all. **PerfView** log file has the following:

```
HeapDump Error: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Initialize(Int32 capacity)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(Int32 capacity, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at Graphs.MemoryGraph..ctor(Int32 expectedSize)
at GCHeapDumper.DumpDotNetHeapData(ClrHeap heap, ICorDebugProcess& debugProcess, Boolean isDump)
at GCHeapDumper.TryGetDotNetDump(Int32 processID)
at GCHeapDumper.CaptureLiveHeapDump(Int32 processID)
at GCHeapDumper.DumpLiveHeap(Int32 processID)
at Program.MainWorker(String[] args)
```

Is it possible to collect memory dump when all memory has been taken already?